# Mysql print SUM() with values of last row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named transactions:

```
transaction_date | some_string       | amount
-----------------+-------------------+--------
Jan 1            | "old_val"         | 10
Jan 2            | "old_val"         | 20
Jan 3            | "most_rest_val"   | 30
-----------------+-------------------+--------
```

Need to get sum of amount and values of last row like this:

```
transaction_date | some_string       | SUM(amount)
-----------------+-------------------+-------------
Jan 3            | "most_recent_val" | 60
-----------------+-------------------+-------------
```

Tried order by, but doesn't work:
`Select transaction_date, some_string, SUM(amount) from transactions Order By transaction_date DESC` returns Sum with values of first row

Any Idea?

Comment: the *sum of the last transaction* (jan 3) is 30, not 60

Comment: `Select MAX(transaction_date), SUM(amount) from transactions`

Comment: `SELECT MAX(transaction_date) AS transaction_date, 'most_recent_val' AS some_string, SUM(amount) FROM transactions;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function instead of an aggregate function to sum up your amount, then `ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1` to access only the last row

```sql
SELECT
  transaction_date,
  some_string,
  SUM(amount) OVER () AS amount
FROM transactions
ORDER BY transaction_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want that last row by itself, then use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(transaction_date) AS transaction_date,
       'most_recent_val' AS some_string,
       SUM(amount)
FROM transactions;
```

Comment: sorry, the table i showed here was the simplified version of what i had. I really need the last row of table with sum of amount. i updated the question, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Use the analytic function `SUM OVER`:

```
select 
  transaction_date,
  some_string,
  sum(amount) over () as total
from mytable
order by transaction_date desc
limit 1;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1975a0e977d1757c4c4f6ebd47b3a140

Comment: It seems, I was a little late posting this ;-)